# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException - SpringBoot autowired constructor contains param that has an autowired declaration that is not being generated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired, spring-bean

I have the following code:
This is my first class that will to call the

```
    @Component
    class DefaultBridge @Autowired constructor(
            private val clientConfig: Config,
            private val client: world.example.Client
    ) : Bridge {

        override fun doEpicStuff(): String {
            val request = createRequest(...)
            val response = client.makeCall(request)
            return response.responseBody
        }
    }
```

The Client being used (world.example.Client) then has the following piece of code:

```
public class Client {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public Response makeCall(Request request) {
    restTemplate.exchange(....)
}
```

}

When running the code. I get the following Error:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

1. Where should I declare the bean when the constructor is autowired?
2. why won't spring automatically create the bean?

I need help understanding the problem so please don't just post the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring dependency injection you can inject a instance of a bean.

In Spring it's called Inversion of Control (IoC) principle. IoC is also known as dependency injection (DI).

You can define depencenies for your bean with member variable or constuctor variables. There are differnt possibilities, for example `@Autowire` as annotation for member variables like your usage.

The container then injects those dependencies when it creates your bean.

**Attention**, however, it is necessary that the spring container knows how the dependency to be injected. There are many ways to teach the container this. The simplest variant is to provide a `@Bean` producer method in a `@Configuration` class. Spring container "scans" all `@Configurations` at the start of the container and "registers" the `@Bean` producer.

Nobody has done a producer for `RestTemplate`. Not Spring self and also no other lib. With many other beans you use, this has already been done, not with `RestTemplate`. You have to provide a `@Bean` producer for `RestTemplate`.

Do this in a new `@Configuration` or in one of your existing `@Configuration`.

A `@Configuration` indicates that a class declares one or more `@Bean` methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime, for example:

```
   @Configuration
   public class RestTemplateConfig {

         @Bean
         public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
             // New instance or more complex config 
             return new RestTemplate();
         }
     }
```

Comment: I ran through some more tutorials and I got to the exact same solution. Thanks so much for the explanation and the help. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Eddie remember to accept the answer if it satisfies you question.

Answer (score 0):

Define RestTemplate as a bean in your configuration class.